# Drupal - Bootstrap theme settings to make NOT responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal, themes, responsive

i am creating a website offline with Bootstrap Theme and my problem is
that i prefer to have fixed widths in my page and not responsive like bootstrap does.
Do you know if there is any solution because in the theme settings i can not see an option to set fixed  and also i can't accomplish it with the css code that i tried.

Thanks in advance,

Antonis

Answer (score 0):

There is no special option for this as I know.

But I've found some solution if you use SASS preprocessor. However if you don't I think you need to use another theme.

First of all set fixed width with:

```
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 990px;
}
```

Than you have to disable css media quarries, just add this code to _default-variables.scss file and rebuild css:

```
$screen-xs-max: 0px !default;
$screen-sm-min: 0px !default;
$screen-sm-max: 0px !default;
$screen-md-min: 0px !default;
$screen-md-max: 0px !default;
$screen-lg-min: 0px !default;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  i am inserting the code to disable media quarries but looks like nothing happens. i pasted it here http://imgur.com/kef2dev